# Java 8 and Java 11 on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, java, openjdk, javafx

The frequent updates for Java versions is causing me headaches in my software engineering course.

I have some students who are doing their project in Java 11, which is not available on the school's machines.  I tried following some of [these directions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-on-ubuntu-18-04) to upgrade to Java 11.  I don't recall my exact steps.  Unfortunately, now some JavaFX things are broken back in Java 8.  After compiling via the command line and running code from other students, I'm receiving this error mid-application:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
```

Even though I think I'm switched back to Java 8:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 3 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                          Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac   1101      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac    1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac           1081      manual mode
```

and

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority    Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1101      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
```

I would like to allow my students to use whichever version of Java they prefer.  How can I fix my setup so that JavaFX works again?  How can I set things up so I can accommodate multiple versions of Java?

Update:

I tried updating using update-java-alternatives as suggested below.  It seems to have failed:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

Update 2:

I followed the new suggestion below.  Here's the entire console output from update-java-alternatives, in an attempt to set myself back to Java 8:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -v -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer to provide /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/idlj to provide /usr/bin/idlj (idlj) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar to provide /usr/bin/jar (jar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner to provide /usr/bin/jarsigner (jarsigner) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc to provide /usr/bin/javadoc (javadoc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap to provide /usr/bin/javap (javap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jcmd to provide /usr/bin/jcmd (jcmd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole to provide /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdb to provide /usr/bin/jdb (jdb) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdeps to provide /usr/bin/jdeps (jdeps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jinfo to provide /usr/bin/jinfo (jinfo) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jmap to provide /usr/bin/jmap (jmap) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps to provide /usr/bin/jps (jps) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jrunscript to provide /usr/bin/jrunscript (jrunscript) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstack to provide /usr/bin/jstack (jstack) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat to provide /usr/bin/jstat (jstat) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd to provide /usr/bin/jstatd (jstatd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/orbd to provide /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmic to provide /usr/bin/rmic (rmic) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/schemagen to provide /usr/bin/schemagen (schemagen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/serialver to provide /usr/bin/serialver (serialver) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/servertool to provide /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/tnameserv to provide /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsgen to provide /usr/bin/wsgen (wsgen) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsimport to provide /usr/bin/wsimport (wsimport) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/xjc to provide /usr/bin/xjc (xjc) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jexec to provide /usr/bin/jexec (jexec) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool to provide /usr/bin/keytool (keytool) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/orbd to provide /usr/bin/orbd (orbd) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/pack200 to provide /usr/bin/pack200 (pack200) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmid to provide /usr/bin/rmid (rmid) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/rmiregistry to provide /usr/bin/rmiregistry (rmiregistry) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/servertool to provide /usr/bin/servertool (servertool) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/tnameserv to provide /usr/bin/tnameserv (tnameserv) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/unpack200 to provide /usr/bin/unpack200 (unpack200) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/appletviewer to provide /usr/bin/appletviewer (appletviewer) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/idlj to provide /usr/bin/idlj (idlj) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jarsigner to provide /usr/bin/jarsigner (jarsigner) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar to provide /usr/bin/jar (jar) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javadoc to provide /usr/bin/javadoc (javadoc) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javap to provide /usr/bin/javap (javap) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jcmd to provide /usr/bin/jcmd (jcmd) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdb to provide /usr/bin/jdb (jdb) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jdeps to provide /usr/bin/jdeps (jdeps) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jinfo to provide /usr/bin/jinfo (jinfo) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jmap to provide /usr/bin/jmap (jmap) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps to provide /usr/bin/jps (jps) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jrunscript to provide /usr/bin/jrunscript (jrunscript) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstack to provide /usr/bin/jstack (jstack) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstatd to provide /usr/bin/jstatd (jstatd) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jstat to provide /usr/bin/jstat (jstat) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/rmic to provide /usr/bin/rmic (rmic) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/schemagen to provide /usr/bin/schemagen (schemagen) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/serialver to provide /usr/bin/serialver (serialver) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsgen to provide /usr/bin/wsgen (wsgen) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/wsimport to provide /usr/bin/wsimport (wsimport) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/xjc to provide /usr/bin/xjc (xjc) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/jconsole to provide /usr/bin/jconsole (jconsole) in manual mode
update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so
```

I then compiled and ran code (both submitted in Java 8 and Java 11, just in case), and got the same exception:

```
MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
        at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
        at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
        at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
```

I tried switching to Java 11 using update-java-alternatives, and the code would no longer compile.  Here's the first compilation error:

```
$ javac *.java
BestMusicPlayer.java:1: error: package javafx.application does not exist  
import javafx.application.Application;
```

This happens for both the Java 8 and Java 11 code that's been submitted to me.

Comment: You should use `update-java-alternatives` because there is usually a lot more that has to be changed than just `java` and `javac`.

Comment: Great!  I tried that, but it looks like it failed:

    $ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 
    update-java-alternatives: plugin alternative does not exist: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/IcedTeaPlugin.so

Comment: The IcedTeaPlugin provides support for java applets in web browsers. It is not installed by default and if you don't need it, you can ignore it. If you want to see the alternatives provided by all java installations, run `update-java-alternatives -v -l`. The `-v` (verbose) option also shows which alternatives _have_ been set (not only the errors): `sudo update-java-alternatives -v -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64` (but only if they changed; if you already switched to openjdk 8, `update-java-alternatives` will only try to set the plugin alternative, which obviously fails)

Comment: I think you were saying that I could ignore that problem (since I'm not worried about browser applets).  I still couldn't get the code to run, so I updated my question with the results I got.

Comment: that was more like a general suggestion and it looks like switching java versions works. I'm sorry if javaFx still doesn't work but I currently don't have an idea why.

Comment: Hello, have you tried running them with Oracle Java instead of OpenJDK? I remember I had some issues to compile code: Oracle Java could make it but not OpenJDK...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an error with the bindings ([arch wiki troubleshooting section](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/java)) I know the docs are for Arch but it might be applicable

> which is a result of some incompatibilities of JavaFX with modern
>   ffmpeg build delivered within Arch Linux repository.
>
> Working solution is to install ffmpeg-compat-55 from AUR.
>
> See
>   https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/70o8o6/using_a_javafx_mediaplayer_in_arch/

I used Java8 with `ffmpeg-compat-54` (not 55 because it didn't compile) and it worked

Again, I don't know the exact case for Ubuntu.